# Spring 4. does getBeanFromClass trigger bean's constructor for prototype beans?

Tags: java, spring

Spring 4. does getBeanFromClass() trigger bean's constructor for prototype beans?
If so, we should be very careful about calling this function, right?
In my code getBeanFromClass is something like this:

```
public static <T> T getBeanFromClass(Class<T> aBeanClass) throws BeansException {
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(aBeanClass);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why should we be very careful?

Comment: suppose in one file. One has already called it to get that bean. Another coder tries to use that bean but didn't see person has created the bean, he may perfectly call this func again to get a fresh new instance which could be not something he really needs.

Comment: So you need to configure a singleton bean not a prototype bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is your method. What we actually care is about that `ApplicationContext#getBean(Class)` (which is actually [`BeanFactory#getBean(class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-)) method. Its javadoc states

> Return the bean instance that uniquely matches the given object type, if any.

So, yes, it returns an instance. For prototype beans, it'll return a newly created instance every time.

Do you have to be careful? Depends entirely on what you're doing. If you need to get a prototype bean instance, then this is exactly what you need to use (if you're working with the `ApplicationContext` directly).